# ui-sref="articles.view({articleId: article._id})" meaning?

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, mean

today i am so confusing about code ui-sref="articles.view({articleId: article._id})"  , i have searched many doc but have not found the answer.Anybody can explain it for me. 
It located in list-articles.client.view.html  in meanjs sample source code.Thank you advance and hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say without seeing more code, but here is what I can tell you.

Angular (in this case ui-router) uses ui-sref tags instead of href tags to change states.  From the outside this behavior will seem identical to someone who doesn't have a background in angular, but in reality ui-sref tags are used to change states in angular.  Inside the ui-sref tag, you pass it an expression saying which state you would like to move to when this element is clicked. So everything you are seeing between the "" symbols is referencing the state you will go to when you click the element.  I would also recommend reading up on parent/child states to see why you are seeing it passed as an object.  More details can be found here.

[angular ui-router docs for ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)

Comment: thank you for your answer, i appreciate it, maybe i write not clear, what i need understand about articles.view , what are this function do ?, i can't find it in api doc in meanjs or http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html. Thank you and fun to answer

Comment: It means there is a state called articles, and within the articles state there is a child state called view.  Look at the statename section in this link.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference

Comment: I maybe understand your explaination, ui-sref=“articles.view({articleId: article._id})” help create href="articles/d43tregt45yujrtegfsdf", it can understand help create url automatically based on route that was defined before. Thank you for spending your time for you.